# How to hide value in URL

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

```
192.168.178.83:18300/Zupdate_we_view.act?name=bunnavitou&position=Research111&sex=Male
```

hide value on url

**from this one :**

```
192.168.178.83:18300/Zupdate_we_view.act?name=bunnavitou&position=Research111&sex=Male
```

==>To this :

```
192.168.178.83:18300/Zupdate_we_view.act?
```

Need Help !! JAVA or JAVA SCRIPT

Comment: Do you mean you want to POST instead of GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to get the url, modify it, and then with javascript replace the "true" url with the one you just modified. Here is what I would do:

```
//get the url
$old_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

//then you modify it
$new_url = ...; 

//then with javascript you replace the url with the new one
<script type="text/javascript">
   if(new_url != '')
   {
      window.history.replaceState({"html":'Title',"pageTitle":'Page Title'}, '', new_url);
   }
</script>
```

This should do the trick, if you really want to use GET ; POST would be better, and you wouldn't have to hide the GET parameters.

Comment: i will try this one !! thz

Answer (score 1):

The best way to hide values on url is to use **POST** method.

Click [HTTP Methods: GET vs. POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) or [GET vs POST](http://www.diffen.com/difference/GET_%28HTTP%29_vs_POST_%28HTTP%29)

for more info about **GET** and **POST** methods.

Comment: jexAjax.execute(function(dat) { 
   console.log(dat.REC);
   grid.dataMgr.set(dat.REC); 
   grid.event.register({e:"dblclickCanvas",f:function(e,cell){
    var json_data=JSON.stringify(cell.getDatarow());
    var convert=JSON.parse(json_data);
    var name=convert["E_NAME"];
    var position=convert["E_POSITION"];
    var sex=convert["E_SEX"];
   
    window.location.href="Zupdate_we_view.act?name="+name+"&position="+position+"&sex="+sex;
   }});
  });

Answer (score 0):

Like others suggested, use POST method, but if you want to stick with GET and JavaScript solution is enough (values can be seen in request same as with POST, but furthermore users with disabled JS will see the values), you can use approach described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 0):

```
Another way is to encode the values on first page & pass those values and decode the value  
on second page.

Using that technique you have no need to post data. User can also read the parameter but 
it is encoded not the real value.

You can use different algorithm to encode/decode parameter on both side.
```

Comment: it talk about encode or decode !! about that things i already do it !!

Comment: var name=getUrlVars()["name"]; 
   var dname=decodeURI(name);
   
   var position=getUrlVars()["position"];
   var dposition=decodeURI(position);
   
   var sex=getUrlVars()["sex"];
   var dsex=decodeURI(sex);

Comment: For hiding you must have to use POST method to send data

Comment: my problem is how to hide url parameter

Comment: hmm...amn not using form ! so how can i use method="post"